# How to duplicate a wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, copy, duplicates, mirror

How can I duplicate a Wordpress plugin so that there are two of the same plugins running with its respective links in the sidebar? I will obviously ensure that each copy of the plugin will use unique tables.

I have been trying to wrap my head around this all day today without any success and Google was not my friend this time. Can anyone give any hints please?

Comment: What is the purpose of duplicating the plugin?

Comment: I am trying to duplicate http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-admin-microblog/screenshots/ as I need to use two different microblogs in my backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a tedious task. First you needs to download the whole plugin and study the core functionality,change the plugin name to a new one, change all the variables used inside it to new one.

Make sure there is no functions conflicting each other. by doing all this you can duplicate it.

In between, what is the need of this?? There may be a easy solution for your problem. First explain what is your context ?

Comment: Would I really need to change all variables inside? Would it not be enough to just adjust the db tables to unique ones?

Comment: Nope. Chance to conflict. Because you are using the same variable name in two places. Also it depends on the plugin nature. Can you tell me which plugin you are trying to duplicate?

Comment: I am trying to duplicate http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-admin-microblog/screenshots/ as I need to use two different microblogs in my backend...